# More complex sorting: How to cateorize data and sort the data within categories? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

i have a question regarding a current program that I am trying to modify.
The current program I have:

```
def extract_names(filename):
  names = []
  f = open(filename, 'rU')
  text = f.read()

  yearmatch = re.search(r'Popularity\sin\s(\d\d\d\d)', text)
  if not yearmatch:
    sys.stderr.write('unavailable year\n')
    sys.exit(1)
  year = yearmatch.group(1)
  names.append(year)

  yeartuples = re.findall(r'<td>(\d+)</td><td>(\w+)</td>\<td>(\w+)</td>', text)#finds all patterns of date, boyname, and girlname, creates tuple)

  rankednames = {}
  for rank_tuple in yeartuples:
    (rank, boyname, girlname) = rank_tuple
    if boyname not in rankednames:
      rankednames[boyname] = rank
    if girlname not in rankednames:
      rankednames[girlname] = rank
  sorted_names = sorted(rankednames.keys(), key=lambda x: int(rankednames[x]), reverse = True)
  for name in sorted_names:
    names.append(name + " " + rankednames[name])
  return names[:20]
#Boilerplate from this point**

def main():

  args = sys.argv[1:]

  if not args:
    print 'usage: [--summaryfile] file [file ...]'
    sys.exit(1)

  summary = False
  if args[0] == '--summaryfile':
    summary = True
    del args[0]

  for filename in args:
    names = extract_names(filename)
    text = '\n'.join(names)

    if summary:
      outf = open(filename + '.summary', 'w')
      outf.write(text + '\n')
      outf.close()
    else:
      print text

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Takes information from a website regarding the most popular babynames of a certain year in a table, uses this data to create a list and print out a list of the babynames in order from the lowest rank (1000) to the highest rank (1). The modification I am trying to make is supposed to sort all of the names by alphabet (a first) but within each group of letters (group of all a's, group of all b's etc.) I am trying to sort the names by descending order within the letter groups, so the lowest ranked name that starts with an a would be the first name to show up. I have tried re.search for each letter but I dont think it works as intended that way. I am having the most trouble with the sorting within the letter categories. Are there any other approaches/solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the call to `sorted`, replace:

```
key=lambda x: int(rankednames[x]), reverse = True
```

with:

```
key=lambda x: (x[0], -int(rankednames[x]))
```

The general point is that you can always use a `tuple` to combine two or more different sort keys with one used first and the other as a "tie-breaker". The specific point is that we can easily simulate `reverse=True` because the key happens to be an integer and therefore can be negated: this trick wouldn't work for a string key.

Comment: so is the "-int(rankednames[x])"  doing the same as "reverse = True"? @SteveJessop

Comment: Well, the `-` is doing the same as `reverse=True`, because for integers `a < b` if and only if `-b < -a`.

Comment: What is "x[0]" doing to sort alphabetically? I'm very new to python so i am slower to understand

Comment: `x[0]` is the first character of `x`.

Comment: I don't really know how to answer that. Python compares strings alphabetically (well, actually in ASCII- or unicode-order, but for English that's the same thing). The string `"A"` sorts before `"B"` in Python, therefore names beginning with A will sort before names beginning with B using this sort key

Comment: Ok. Are there any other possible ways to acheive this without modifying the lambda function?

Comment: @ihk47. Sure. First sort the names exactly as you do in your posted code. Then, create a `thing = collections.defaultdict(list)`, and run through all the sorted names doing `thing[x[0]].append(x)`. Finally, run through `for key in sorted(thing.keys())` and do whatever you like with each element of `thing[key]` in turn. You'll visit first the As in order of rank, then the Bs, etc.