# More complex sorting: How to sort within a category?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

i have a question regarding a current program that I am trying to modify. The current program I have:

```
def extract_names(filename):
  names = []
  f = open(filename, 'rU')
  text = f.read()

  yearmatch = re.search(r'Popularity\sin\s(\d\d\d\d)', text)
  if not yearmatch:
    sys.stderr.write('unavailable year\n')
    sys.exit(1)
  year = yearmatch.group(1)
  names.append(year)

  yeartuples = re.findall(r'<td>(\d+)</td><td>(\w+)</td>\<td>(\w+)</td>', text)#finds all patterns of date, boyname, and girlname, creates tuple)

  rankednames = {}
  for rank_tuple in yeartuples:
    (rank, boyname, girlname) = rank_tuple
    if boyname not in rankednames:
      rankednames[boyname] = rank
    if girlname not in rankednames:
      rankednames[girlname] = rank
  sorted_names = sorted(rankednames.keys(), key=lambda x: int(rankednames[x]), reverse = True)
  for name in sorted_names:
    names.append(name + " " + rankednames[name])
  return names[:20]
#Boilerplate from this point**

def main():

  args = sys.argv[1:]

  if not args:
    print 'usage: [--summaryfile] file [file ...]'
    sys.exit(1)

  summary = False
  if args[0] == '--summaryfile':
    summary = True
    del args[0]

  for filename in args:
    names = extract_names(filename)
    text = '\n'.join(names)

    if summary:
      outf = open(filename + '.summary', 'w')
      outf.write(text + '\n')
      outf.close()
    else:
      print text

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Takes information from a website regarding the most popular baby names of a certain year in a table, uses this data to create a list and print out a list of the baby names in order from the lowest rank (1000) to the highest rank (1). The modification I am trying to make is supposed to sort all of the names by alphabet (a first) but within each group of letters (group of all a's, group of all b's etc.) I am trying to sort the names by descending order within the letter groups, so the lowest ranked name that starts with an a would be the first name to show up.I was initially able to do this by modifying the lambda function so that `sorted_names = sorted(rankednames.keys(),key=lambda x: (x[0], int(rankednames[x], reverse = True))` however, I want to be able to achieve this without the modification of the lambda function.

Comment: Why cannot you modify the lambda function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [More complex sorting: How to cateorize data and sort the data within categories? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373701/more-complex-sorting-how-to-cateorize-data-and-sort-the-data-within-categories)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious fix is indeed to modify your lambda function, so that it returns a 2-tuple `(letter, rank)`. Since you want to sort increasing by letter and decreasing by rank, you'll want to negate the latter (rather than using `reverse=True`):

```
sorted_names = sorted(rankednames, key=lambda x: (x[0], -int(rankednames[x])))
```

The only alternative I can think of is to sort twice, first by rank (in reverse) and then by first letter:

```
sorted_names = sorted(sorted(rankednames,
                             key=lambda x: int(rankednames[x]),
                             reverse=True),
                      key=lambda x: x[0])
```

This works because Python's Timsort is stable (it keeps equal keyed values in the same order they had in the input). This is probably going to be a bit slower than sorting just once, though it's still `O(N log(N))` in the average case.